# Russian character gets converted to different random English character while calling a HTTP API

Tags: java, servlets

I am doing a `POST` request to a HTTP server but the parameter whose value is Russian gets converted to some random English alphanumeric characters. Here's my code part:-

```
    URL url = new URL("http", "vlinux", 9608, "/Adjust");
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "JavaClient/7.0.2/RIIApiClient/1.0.0");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    dataOut.writeBytes(urlString);
    dataOut.flush();
    dataOut.close();
    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        System.out.println("SUCCESS...check log");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error while executing ");
    } finally {
    connection.disconnect();
    }
```

Am I not setting the right `requestProperty`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you question is not clear what is the current content of the `urlString` and how it was generated. And this is important.

**Short:**

**For the preparation of the request:**

- use `URLEncoder` to encode the parameter names and values.
- use `OutputStreamWriter` to set encoding
- use `BufferedWriter` in order not to handle with bytes

Snipplet:

```
String urlString =  URLEncoder.encode("word", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("молоко", "UTF-8");

DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
BufferedWriter dataOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

dataOut.write(urlString);
```

**For the response use :**

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
reader.readLine()
```

**Long: Example with Client and Servlet:**

Client:

```
package testingThings.formEncoding;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http", "localhost", 8080, "/jee6/EncodingTester");
        System.out.println("url: " + url);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "JavaClient/7.0.2/RIIApiClient/1.0.0");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        String urlString =  URLEncoder.encode("word", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("молоко", "UTF-8");

        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        BufferedWriter dataOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

        dataOut.write(urlString);
        dataOut.flush();
        dataOut.close();

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            System.out.println("SUCCESS...check log");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Response Code: " +  responseCode);
        }

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    }

}
```

Servlet:

```
package testingThings.formEncoding;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/EncodingTester")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().append(request.getParameter("word"));

        getServletContext().log("param word in servlet:" + request.getParameter("word"));
    }

    /**
     * allow requests just for testing, 
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

}
```

Output-Client:

```
url: http://localhost:8080/jee6/EncodingTester
SUCCESS...check log
молоко
```

Output-Servlet:

```
... ServletContext.log():param word in servlet:молоко
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying any character encoding anywhere and you're using `dataOut.writeBytes(urlString);` which will certainly garble any non ASCII characters (from the Javadoc):

> Writes out the string to the underlying output stream as a sequence of
>   bytes. Each character in the string is written out, in sequence, by
>   discarding its high eight bits. If no exception is thrown, the counter
>   written is incremented by the length of s.